# Verify the solution of first order linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The solution of $$y'(t) = a(t)\,y(t)+b(t)$$ is given by $$y(t) = y_0\,e^{A(t)} + e^{A(t)} \int_0^{t}b(s)e^{-A(s)}\,ds$$

I'd like to show it's fulfilling the ode above by the differentiation of it:

$$\begin{align}&\displaystyle{\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[y_0\,e^{A(t)} + e^{A(t)} \int_0^{t}b(s)e^{-A(s)}\,ds\right]} \\\\
=& \displaystyle{y_0\,a(t)\,e^{A(t)}}+ \displaystyle{\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[e^{A(t)} \int_0^{t}b(s)e^{-A(s)}\,ds\right]} \\ \\
=& \displaystyle{y_0\,a(t)\,e^{A(t)}}+\displaystyle{a(t)\,e^{A(t)}\,\int_0^{t}b(s)e^{-A(s)}\,ds+e^{A(t)}}\,\displaystyle{\dfrac{d}{dt}\left[\int_0^{t}b(s)e^{-A(s)}\,ds\right]} \\ \\ 
=& \displaystyle{y_0\,a(t)\,e^{A(t)}}+\displaystyle{a(t)\,e^{A(t)}\,\int_0^{t}b(s)e^{-A(s)}\,ds+}\displaystyle{e^{A(t)}\,\left(b(t)\,e^{-A(t)}+\int_0^tb(s)\,e^{-A(s)}\,ds\right)}\end{align}$$

What's not the result I'm looking for. I guess I messed up differentiating the integral. Or even before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct result for the last derivative is
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t b(s)\,e^{-A(s)}\,ds=b(t)\,e^{-A(t)},
$$
where
$$
A(t)=\int_0^t a(s)\,ds.
$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
y'(t)&=\frac{d}{dt}\left[y_0\,e^{A(t)}+e^{A(t)}\int_0^t b(s)\,e^{-A(s)}\,ds\right] \\
&=y_0\,a(t)\,e^{A(t)}+a(t)\,e^{A(t)}\int_0^t b(s)\,e^{-A(s)}\,ds+b(t) \\
&=a(t)\left[y_0\,e^{A(t)}+e^{A(t)}\int_0^t b(s)\,e^{-A(s)}\,ds\right]+b(t) \\
&=a(t)\,y(t)+b(t).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that mistake! I was blended by Leibniz-integration-rule.